# How would I implement SURF in objC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opencv, surf

I need to implement SURF algorithm in objc iOS.
I have searched on openCV and also tried to implement following examples

[jonmarimba](https://github.com/jonmarimba/OpenCV-iOS) and  [ishai jaffe](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-surf-images/)

The examples are not working and I need to make any one of them work so atleast I can get relieved that yes SURF can work on iOS as well. I have tried to build from scratch but I am totally FUSED with SHORT CIRCUIT.

I am trying to use openCV 2.4.2 in jonmarimba's example.

And also trying to use iOS5.1.1 with Xcode 4.3

Comment: OpenCV is open-source, so try to look into sources...

Comment: @Astor please help me out, i am unable to do anything.... i am feeling as if i am crippled

Comment: download OpenCV sources, find needed functions and rewrite them into objc

Comment: As a caution: [SURF is patented, and a license fee is required for its use](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/what-are-some-free-alternatives-to-sift-surf-that-can-be-used-in-commercial-app), so you may want to keep that in mind before getting too far into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: Go with OpenCVs C++-interface. Objective-C is a strict super set of C, so you can just use it.

To get a grip on the topic take a look at OpenCVs official [**docs**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html) and the example code about [**Feature Description**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html?highlight=surf).

The next step is to grab a copy of the current OpenCV version for iOS. As of version [2.4.2 OpenCV has official iOS-support](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#242) and you just need the **opencv2.framework**.

To convert an UIImage to a cv::Mat use this function:

```
￼static UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& m) {
    CV_Assert(m.depth() == CV_8U);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:m.data length:m.elemSize()*m.total()];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = m.channels() == 1 ?
        CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray() : CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(m.cols, m.cols, m.elemSize1()*8, m.elemSize()*8,
        m.step[0], colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
        provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); return finalImage;
}
```

… and vice-versa:

```
static void UIImageToMat(const UIImage* image, cv::Mat& m) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width, rows = image.size.height;
    m.create(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(m.data, m.cols, m.rows, 8,
        m.step[0], colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef); CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

The rest of the work you have to do is plain OpenCV Stuff. So grab you a coffee and start working.

If you need some "inspiration" take a look at this repo [gsoc2012 - /ios/trunk](http://code.opencv.org/svn/gsoc2012/ios/trunk/) It's dedicated to OpenCV + iOS.

Comment: plz help me... I am revisitng and I am stuck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033063/where-to-add-surf